# multi module maven spring inject beans

Tags: spring, maven, dependency-injection, module, vaadin

I have two maven module:

1. logic (Spring project with beans etc.) - packed to .jar
2. Web (Vaadin project with spring nature) - packet to .war

In Web .pom I have dependecy to logic. In java code autowired etc. is ok.
I want use beans from logic in Web project.

My web.xml (Web project): path: ../src/main/webapp/WEB-INF

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext.xml

    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

My application context: (path: ../src/main/webapp/WEB-INF)

```
<beans ...
<context:annotation-config />

<import resource="logic.xml"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="b2b"
    annotation-config="true" />
```

logic.xml contains configuration for beans in logic module. Base package name is b2b.

In UI class I have:

```
@Autowired
private CompanyService companyService;
```

I try in many ways to get beans, but always companyService is null after start Web.

What I should add to get beans from logic module visible in Web module?

UI class:

```
@Theme("mytheme")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Controller
public class MyVaadinUI extends UI
{ }
```

I also make as mentions here for vaadin V7: [enter link description here](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Spring%20Integration?p%255Fr%255Fp%255F185834411%255Ftitle=Spring%2520Integration)

but not help.

This is my UI class:

```
enter code here
@Theme("mytheme")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Controller
public class MyVaadinUI extends UI
{

 SpringContextHelper helper = new SpringContextHelper(VaadinServlet.getCurrent().getServletContext());

private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyVaadinUI.class);

@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MyVaadinUI.class, widgetset = "b2b.frontend.AppWidgetSet")
public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
}

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setMargin(true);
    setContent(layout);
    final CompanyService companyService = (CompanyService) helper.getBean("companyService");

    Button button = new Button("Click Me");
    button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            //layout.addComponent(new Label("Thank you for clicking"));

            LOGGER.info("pushed the button");
            layout.addComponent(new Label("aa " +companyService +" Thank you for clicking"));

        }
    });
    layout.addComponent(button);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You didn't presented your UI class. I suspect that UI is not a Spring managed bean, thus autowiring is off. Or your UI is annotated as Spring bean, but is created with **new** operator, not taken from Spring context.

Well, if you made it as you explained, it must work. No mercy. I made a simple project https://github.com/michaldo/multi-module-vaadin-spring and it works

Answer (score 0):

You can split your UI in 2 layers - views (UI) and controllers (intermediate class between view and your logic classes). Your controller can be created from view in standard way i.e. with *new* operator.

Then annotate your controller class with @Configurable:

```
@Configurable
public class MyController 
{
   @Autowired
   private MyService service;
}
```

Configurable tells Spring that this bean created out of Spring context should still be a subject for dependency injection. To make this work, you'll need AspectJ runtime on your classpath + add aspectj compiling stage to your build - change pom.xml for ui project as follows:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Aspectj plugin to make Spring aware of non-managed
        beans and support autowiring -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <!-- Required as the plugin does not resolve this by default -->
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <aspectLibraries>
          <aspectLibrary>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
          </aspectLibrary>
        </aspectLibraries>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
            <goal>test-compile</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

I'm using this approach in my project and works pretty well.